# Creating a custom run configuration using IntelliJ SDK and adding Build task in Before launch section

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm following the tutorial in [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/run_configurations.html) section of IntelliJ IDEA SDK.

Following the tutorial, I will get a new configuration panel with an empty "Before launch" section. That section is added by default.

[image]

I would like to specify some targets by default, i.e. at least the Build target as done in several plugins (see next picture)

[image]

I'm trying to understand how, but I cannot find any example nor documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How can I add default `build` task?

Your run configuration (`DemoRunConfiguration` in the example) should implement `RunProfileWithCompileBeforeLaunchOption`. This interface doesn't provide any methods to implement, so this is a kind of mark. `build` task will be added automatically, no additional steps are required.

## How can I add my own task to `before launch` section?

Your `plugin.xml` should contain a line with `stepsBeforeRunProvider`

```
<stepsBeforeRunProvider implementation="com.MyBeforeRunProvider" id="myBeforeRun"/>
```

For that you should create "before run provider" with "before run task".

```
public class BeforeRunProvider extends BeforeRunTaskProvider<MyBeforeRunTask> {
    @Override
    public Key<MyBeforeRunTask> getId() {
        return Key.create("ThisIsId");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Nice name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(MyBeforeRunTask task) {
        return "Description";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Icon getIcon() {
        return AllIcons.Actions.Compile;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MyBeforeRunTask createTask(@NotNull RunConfiguration runConfiguration) {
        return new MyBeforeRunTask(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean executeTask(@NotNull DataContext dataContext, @NotNull RunConfiguration runConfiguration, @NotNull ExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment, @NotNull MyBeforeRunTask myBeforeRunTask) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the task:

```
public class MyBeforeRunTask extends BeforeRunTask<MyBeforeRunTask> {

    protected MyBeforeRunTask(@NotNull Key<MyBeforeRunTask> providerId) {
        super(providerId);
        setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```